# Existing dualboot xubuntu & win10, added new drive, how best to config system?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, xubuntu

[image: harddrivespace]

Hi folks. My current setup is a dual boot with xubuntu 20.10 given 1TB win10 given 800GB, and another little bit for the boot partition. All working lovely. But I'm running out of space, so I bought another identical drive, which I've just installed & is currently unformatted & unallocated.

If it were you, how would you configure this?

Conceptually I guess I'd prefer to have one OS per drive, but that'll mean cloning win10 to the new drive I presume...and then re-authenticating windows (not that hard IIRC)... and reconfiguring GRUB? And then deleting the backup, deleting that partition (nvme0n1p3), and growing the xubuntu partition to fill the drive?

As much as the technical "how to", I guess I'm equally interested in what people's preferred angle of attack would be.

Cheers!

Comment: They don’t like opinion based questions on here but I’d clone the EFI partition and the Xubuntu partition to the new drive then expand Xubuntu. I’d delete the Xubuntu partition on the old drive and keep the EFI partition on the old drive so you have an EFI on both. This can be helpful if you have a drive failure at some point. I’d fix any boot issues when booting either drive and finally expand the Windows partition using Windows disk manager

Comment: Thanks. So Moving the linux partitions will be easier? Makes sense - and exactly why the tactical is sometimes more important than the technical! Any aversion to cloning with `dd` [(e.g.)](https://www.tecmint.com/clone-linux-partitions/)? It looks like the option is blocked in gparted, presumably because the drives are mounted, so feasibly this is the case with dd also, in which case... gparted via liveUSB? Cheers! Edit: oh p.s., if you want to make this an answer then I can accept it.

Comment: I have no experience of cloning with dd so I cannot tell you if you would have the same issue with the partition being mounted. GParted with a live usb is the way to go. Alternatively Macrium Reflect Free will do this run from Windows. Saves making a live usb if you don’t have one handy. Feel free to answer your own question and accept it a day later once you have sorted it. My comments were only an opinion not really an answer.

Comment: Hi again. Weird one. So I copied EFI & Xubuntu to the new drive in gparted, rebooted to windows, fine. Rebooted to xubuntu, fine. All good so far (haven't deleted yet). But: presumably it should still be booting to old xubuntu, however, Properties for my Home folder says I have enough space that it must be New Xubuntu. Are both drives acting as mirrored? I'm a bit worried about deleting Old Xubuntu, even though it might be totally fine... Any intel appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Having cloned the Xubuntu you should have two drives with the same UUID. UUID’s are unique so things that rely on that can go wrong. Your /etc/fstab file may use UUID’s to specify which partition to mount where. If it uses /dev/sda# type references the disk that is booted depends upon how that reference was allocated. When you add a device that allocation is disturbed. The extra space you now have should be enough evidence to be safe to delete the old partition. The drives will not act as mirrors, they are just identical except for any changes since cloning.

Comment: Having deleted the Old Xubuntu partition from the image above, New Xubuntu does indeed work fine, huzzah. However - windows now no longer works. Won't start. Tried all the windows options, startup repair etc. Presumably it's expecting to be the third partition and now it's the second (or similar)? It should be in the same place, only now it has empty space in front of it instead of an ext4 partition. Can I just move the windows partition in gparted? Or do I need to fix the windows MBR somehow? Thanks again!

Comment: If you set your bios to boot the original disk can you boot both? If not I think you need the Windows installer to repair the booting of Windows. I added a second disk to one of my systems and just copied the EFI partition to the new disk. That will boot Windows only from the original and Windows or Linux from the new. In your scenario the original disk should be capable of booting either OS if you are using UUID referencing in /etc/fstab. I would have expected it to boot Windows from either disk but I didn’t change anything on my Windows disk. Google or YouTube should provide a Windows fix

Comment: I’ve no idea if this will work but if you copy the Xubuntu partition to the original disk Windows may boot again. Then delete the Xubuntu partition on the original disk using Windows disk manager and resize the Windows partition with Windows disk manager also. If you don’t have good backups backup the Windows partition before doing anything else

Comment: Cheers for the thoughts fella. Turning into a right pain. Did boot repair which killed everything, couldn't get into xubuntu. Did it again, can get into xubuntu again but still no windows. Chkdsk suggestions from windows repair disk don't help. Looking to try your last suggestion but boot repair seems to have killed GRUB on my multiboot USB which means I can't run my liveUSB to do gparted, and I can't fix multiboot without a windows install....nightmare.

Comment: It would be worth creating a blank partition on the original disk where Xubuntu was. You can do that with the GParted in Xubuntu. I think it’s a case of Windows wanting to boot the third partition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With full credit to @PonJar:

1. In Gparted on a liveUSB: clone the EFI and Old Xubuntu partitions to the new drive.
2. Still In Gparted on a liveUSB: expand New Xubuntu to fill the new drive.
3. Still In Gparted on a liveUSB: give Old Xubuntu a new random UUID. You'll have to run `e2fsck` in terminal but it's pretty much as it tells you to do, then try again with the random UUID.
4. In Windows, computer management, disk manager, delete Old Xubuntu.
5. In windows, download [Mini Tool Partition Wizard Free](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html), and expand Windows to fill the empty space.

You may have to repair GRUB. I used [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) a number of times, and found it worked better when installed into a liveUSB than when used as part of a [YUMI Multiboot USB (fat32 UEFI+BIOS)](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/), because it gave all the options. However Boot Repair did also mangle the GRUB on that LiveUSB, which can be fixed by using a separate windows install and adding another tool to the USB then saving.

Comment: Sounds like you are sorted now. I’ve not ever worked on a disk where Windows was not at the beginning. Did placing a partition where Xubuntu was help?

Comment: Yeah I reckon that did the trick. And I suspect your blank partition trick would have worked also, after I'd deleted the Old Xubuntu already, rather than resizing New Xubuntu, copying it, running into all kinds of issues with insufficient space to reinstall lightdm and having to do everything in the command line, etc. Hassle!